# Is there an option to upload photos / videos from within emails using AMP?

Tags: amp-html, amp-email

Google has started supporting AMP within Gmail to allow dynamic emails. I was wondering if there is any way to use it to allow users to upload photos/videos and then submit them in-mail (similarly to a form/questionnaires which are supported).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.

You can use [`amp-form`](https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/components/amp-form/) to design your form, where you can provide `file input` 
 HTML control.
Apart from this, you'll have to write a service/ API to accept the form data.

Answer (score 0):

File upload is not yet supported for AMP Emails due to some security concerns. https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/38460